Balanced Sinkhorn-Knopp normalization proof
It is well-known that a non-negative squared matrix with at least one positive diagonal entries converges to doubly stochastic matrix (i.e., (sum of each row) = (sum of each column) = 1) by alternatively normalizing rows and columns [1].
Mathematically, we can write operations for alternatively normalizing rows and columns as
\begin{equation}
    a_{ij}^{(k+1)} = \begin{cases}
        \big(\sum_{t} a_{it}^{(k)}\big)^{-1} \cdot a_{ij}^{(k)}, & \mod (k,2) = 0 \\
        \big(\sum_{t} a_{tj}^{(k)}\big)^{-1} \cdot a_{ij}^{(k)}, & \mod (k,2) = 1
    \end{cases} 
\end{equation}
for matrix sequences $A^{(0)}=[a_{ij}^{(0)}], A^{(1)}=[a_{ij}^{(1)}], A^{(2)}=[a_{ij}^{(2)}], \cdots$.
However, the above equation is intuitive but not looks that fancy. So I came across a new formula to obtain doubly stochastic matrix as
\begin{equation}
    a_{ij}^{(k+1)} = \big(\sum_{t} a_{it}^{(k)} \sum_{t} a_{tj}^{(k)}\big)^{-1/2} \cdot a_{ij}^{(k)},
\end{equation}
and I called this method as balanced normalization instead of alternative normalization.
I experimentally showed that balanced normalization also converges to doubly stochastic matrix, but I cannot prove its convergence.
I would really appreciate your valuable ideas, comments to prove it.
[1] R. Sinkhorn and P. Knopp. Concerning nonnegative matrices and doubly stochastic matrices. Pacific J. Math.,21(2):343–348, 1967.

Looks interesting. I think the key is to find the variables that are always sum-one. In the original case, it is trivially row-sum and column-sum, but you may want to find it for your case.

It seems that the balanced normalization is firstly considered in the following paper though a rigorous proof still remains incomplete. Differentiable Sparsification for Deep Neural Networks, https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.03201
